# typeof(function.arguments) is object

Tags: javascript

Let we have a simple function

```
make=function(){ }
```

Why when we trying to display `alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(make.arguments));` we have an error

```
[18:33:06.588] TypeError: make.arguments is not an object @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:28
```

but

```
alert(typeof(make.arguments));
```

displays `object`?

Comment: `make.arguments` is `null`. In JavaScript `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: var make = function(){}; console.log(make.arguments); @VisioN - right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `typeof X` returns `"object"` it doesn't mean that `X` is an object.

In the code you've provided `make.arguments` property is `null`, and according to ECMAScript Specification section [**11.4.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) `typeof null` returns `"object"`.

So implicitly you are executing the following code: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(null)`, which as a result throws the `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is get the arguments passed to a function the following is sufficient:

```
function test () {
   console.log(arguments) // Appears to be an array '[]'.
}
```

Let's take a look at the type:

```
function test () {
   console.log(arguments instanceof Array) // False. It's an object.
}
```

Turns out that arguments is not an array at all and some trickery is required:

```
function test () {
   var args = [].slice.call(arguments); 
   console.log(args instanceof Array) // True. It's an array.
   console.log(typeof args) // Object. Sigh.
}
```

The point I am making (and better explained by VisionN) is that typeof works as follows:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Take a look at the table. Null AND arguments (which is an object) will be type 'object' as will empty arrays.